# Mapview callout only appears if I tap the very top-left corner of my custom annotation view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a MapKit implementation with a custom annotation view and a callout view. For some extremely annoying reason (I've been stuck on this for days...), the callout view only shows up if I tap the top-left corner of the annotation view.

I implemented the pointInside function for my annotation view and the iPhone does indeed see that I am tapping in the middle of the annotation, it just doesn't do anything following that tap.

How do I fix this ? I need to be able to tap anywhere on the custom annotation view to see the callout.

Please help if you have any idea on how to fix this.

**EDIT**

Here is my viewForAnnotation implementation

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
            return nil
        }

        var customCalloutView = CustomCalloutView()
        let rentalAnnotation = annotation as? RentalAnnotation
            let identifier = "pin"
            var customAnnotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            customAnnotationView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            customAnnotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -customAnnotationView.loadedView.frame.size.height / 2)
            customAnnotationView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(25, -2)
            let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
            customCalloutView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
            customCalloutView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        if let annotation = annotation as? RentalAnnotation {

            if let dequeuedView = rentalsMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? CustomAnnotationView {
                dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                if let label = dequeuedView.label {
                    label.text = "$ \(annotation.price)"
                }
                dequeuedView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(25, -2)
                dequeuedView.canShowCallout = true
                dequeuedView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -customAnnotationView.loadedView.frame.size.height / 2)
                dequeuedView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = customCalloutView
                customAnnotationView = dequeuedView
            } else {
                customAnnotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                customAnnotationView.label?.text = "$ \(annotation.price)"
                customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
                customAnnotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -customAnnotationView.loadedView.frame.size.height / 2)
                customAnnotationView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(25, -2)
                customAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = customCalloutView
 = customCalloutView

            }
        }
            return customAnnotationView

        // if annotation is nil, then return a nil for MKAnnotationView
    }
```

Here is also my custom subclass of MKAnnotationView

```
class CustomAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel?
    var loadedView = UIView()

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        loadedView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomAnnotationViewDesign", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)!
        self.addSubview(loadedView)
        label?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        if point.x > loadedView.frame.minX && point.x < loadedView.frame.maxX && point.y > loadedView.frame.minY && point.y < loadedView.frame.maxY {
            print("Point inside")
            return true
        } else {
            print("Point not inside")
            return false
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code work with.

Comment: Just added some code as an edit.

Comment: 6 years later and this is still a problem. Did you ever figure this out?